# Solr query on read/deny roles

Tags: solr, indexing

We have a custom Solr index which includes read and deny roles. Both are added as predicates using the following code:

```
protected virtual IQueryable<TIndexable> ApplyDenyUserRules<TIndexable>
(IQueryable<TIndexable> queryable) where TIndexable : IEntity
{
  if (Context.User == null || Context.User.IsAdministrator || 
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.User.Name))
  {
      return queryable;
  }

  bool includeIndirectRoles;

  if       
  (!bool.TryParse(
   Settings.GetSetting("DFS.Membership.IncludeIndirectRoles"), out 
   includeIndirectRoles))
  {
    includeIndirectRoles = false;
  }

  var roles = RolesInRolesManager.GetRolesForUser(Context.User, 
              includeIndirectRoles);
  var userRoles = roles.Select(r => r.Name.
                  Replace("\\", string.Empty).Replace("™", string.Empty).
                  Replace(" ",string.Empty));

  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TIndexable>();
  var subPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TIndexable>();

  subPredicate = userRoles.Aggregate(subPredicate, (current, role) => 
                 current.And(i => !i.DenyRules.Contains(role)));

  predicate = predicate.And(subPredicate);

  if (predicate.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.Constant)
  {
    queryable = queryable.Filter(predicate);
  }

  return queryable;
}

protected virtual IQueryable<TIndexable> ApplyReadRoles<TIndexable>
(IQueryable<TIndexable> queryable) where TIndexable : IEntity
{
  if (Context.User == null || Context.User.IsAdministrator || 
     Context.User.Roles == null || !Context.User.Roles.Any())
     {          
       return queryable;
     }

     bool includeIndirectRoles;

     if (!bool.TryParse(
         Settings.GetSetting("DFS.Membership.IncludeIndirectRoles"), out 
         includeIndirectRoles))
     {
       includeIndirectRoles = false;
     }

     var roles = RolesInRolesManager.GetRolesForUser(Context.User, 
                 includeIndirectRoles);

     var userRoles = roles.Select(r => r.Name.Replace("\\", 
                     string.Empty).Replace("™", string.Empty).Replace(" ", 
                     string.Empty));
     var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<TIndexable>();
     var subPredicate = userRoles.Aggregate(predicate, (current, role) => 
                        current.Or(i => i.ReadRoles.Contains(role)));
     predicate = predicate.And(subPredicate);
     if (predicate.Body.NodeType != ExpressionType.Constant)
     {
       queryable = queryable.Filter(predicate);
     }

     return queryable;
}
```

This returns the following Solr query:

```
fq=((-denyrules_sm:(sitecoregruppe) AND -denyrules_sm:
   (sitecoreDigizuiteDAMforSitecoreAdministrators)) AND (readroles_sm:
   (sitecoregruppe) OR readroles_sm:
   (sitecoreDigizuiteDAMforSitecoreAdministrators)))
```

which to me looks valid, but for some reason does not work. If I use the exact same code with lucene indexing then it works just fine. One thing I have noticed is that my field is in the Solr index, but as I am actually not using deny roles in my installation, then it is always empty.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Magnus

Comment: Are you getting any error message why the query is rejected? You could try running the same query from Solr UI.

Comment: Could show us what values are stored in readroles_sm and denyrules_sm fields in the Solr?

Comment: @grg, no error message at all and running it from solr ui yield no results, however if i remove the denyrules part, then I get results

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich, the readroles looks like this:
"readroles_sm": [
          "sitecoreDigizuiteDAMforSitecoreContributors",
          "extranetanonymous",
          "sitecoreDigizuiteDAMforSitecoreEditors",
          "sitecoreDigizuiteDAMforSitecoreAdministrators"
        ],
the denyrules are not set in sitecore and hence are not even there. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Try to remove the condition which related with denyrules_sm and see if you get any results.

Comment: If the denyrules_sm field is not presented in the index, we can imagine your query (in the optimistic case, when readroles_sm exactly matching the result): fq=((False AND False) AND (True OR True), but unfurtunally it always False

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich, it is indeed a valid field, but it has no values. This works just fine with lucene, but seems to not work for Solr. Furthermore, removing it does indeed yield expected result, but it should work without. Denyrules only has a value if the user actively sets deny access in Sitecore (the red x in the access viewer) and therefore often it does not have a value.